# Limit of sequence of whole numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of whole numbers such that $a_n \rightarrow a$. I need to show that there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n = a$ for all $n > n_0$.

Why would this ever be the case where the limit value is contained inside the sequence? My understanding of limits was that they are values that a sequence tends towards yet never reaches (like how the sequence $1/n$ never reaches $0$ but instead comes infinitely close).

Comment: The "yet never reaches" isn't part of the definition of a limit.

Comment: In general, it is possible for the limit to be different from all the values of the sequence (or be equal to some and not others, etc.). The point of the exercise here is to show that if the sequence only take integer values and converges, then it must be stationary. You need both hypotheses to get the conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nah. Use [a strict definition of the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)#Limit_of_a_sequence).

If $a$ is not a whole number, then $\epsilon=\frac12\min\{|a-n|\mid 0\le n\in\mathbb Z\}$. Then you must find a natural number $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$. But $a_n$ is not a whole number because $|a_n-a|\notin\{|a-n| \mid 0\le n\in\mathbb Z\}$.

So, $a$ must be a whole number. Then, let $\epsilon$ as less than 1. Then there exists a natural number $N$ such that...
$$
n\ge N \Rightarrow|a_n-a|<\epsilon<1
$$
So. the whole number $a_n$ must be $a$. (because the difference between the two disticnt whole numbers must be a natural number.)

So, this follows...
$$
n\ge N\Rightarrow a_n=a
$$

Comment: So just for me to understand fully, are you saying that if we choose an $\epsilon$ that is less than 1, then the only possible value of $a_n$ to satisfy the definition of the limit whilst still being an integer must be $a$?

Comment: @adr555 Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 3):

If $a_n$ is a real sequence, then $a_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$ means that, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $n_0$ such that
$$n > n_0 \implies |a_n - a| < \varepsilon. \tag{$\star$}$$
Nothing in the above suggests that $a_n \neq a$. If we wanted to specify this in the definition (which, to be clear, makes a notion of a limit that is that is **not equivalent** to the usual definition of a limit), then we could write
$$n > n_0 \implies 0 < |a_n - a| < \varepsilon.$$
The true definition is perfectly fine with $a_n = a$ for some (or even all!) $n$. Indeed, if $a_n = a$ is a constant sequence, then for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we can choose $n_0$ to be anything. Indeed, $(\star)$ becomes:
$$n > n_0 \implies 0 < \varepsilon,$$
which is true simply because the conclusion is true. This proves that $a_n \to a$, i.e. the constant sequence $a$ converges (as expected) to $a$. That is, it is a sequence that attains its limit (all the time, in fact), which suggests that your understanding needs some fine-tuning.

It's quite common for students to walk away with this idea that limits cannot be attained. Teachers will often emphasise this point, as it showcases some of the utility of limits. For example, students have some trouble with the idea that $0.999...$ is equal to $1$, partially because the value of $1$ is never "attained" by using more and more $9$s. But, if you think about it in terms of limits, one can prove the limit of $0.9, 0.99, 0.999, \ldots$ is exactly equal to $1$. In this case, we use limits to talk about a number not attained by an approximating sequence, but just because this happens to be an interesting case, doesn't mean that it's necessarily true for all limits.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful explanation! I am still wrapping my head around the convergence of sequences and their limits, but this clarifies a lot.

Comment: @adr555 You're welcome!